# Batch code 10 not expected at this time

Tags: batch-file, runtime-error

This is my code. It crashes as soon as it starts.

```
if %CHO%==1 (
    if %WEP%==None (
        set DMGmod=0
    )
    if %WEP%==Broadsword (
        set DMGmod=5
    )
    if %WEP%==Shortsword (
        set DMGmod=4
    )
    if %WEP%==Axe (
        set DMGmod=7
    )
    if %WEP%==Mace (
        set DMGmod=10
    )
    if %WEP%==Dagger (
        set DMGmod=3
    )
    if %WEP%==Shortbow (
        set DMGmod=5
    )
    if %WEP%==Longbow (
        set DMGmod=8
    )
    if %WEP%==Crossbow (
        set DMGmod=15
    )
    if %DMGPTN%==true (
        set /a DMGmod=!DMGmod!+10
    )
    set /a DMG=%DMG%+!DMGmod!
    if %ATKPTN%==true set /a ATKmod=%ATK%+10
    set min=1
    set max=!ATKmod!
    call random.bat
    if %num% GEQ %eDEX% (
        set min=1
        set max=!DMGmod!
        call random.bat
        if %DMGPTN%==true (
            set /a damage=%num%+10
            goto hit
        ) else (
            set damage=%num%
            goto hit
        )
    ) else (
        goto miss
    )
)
```

When I run this code, it crashes and says "10 was not expected at this time". I checked it over multiple times and I can't find what went wrong. I don't know what it means by 10 not being expected. I used 10 as a number for a variable, not as a command. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see, that you know how to use delayed expansion. But you missed that `%num%` should also be delayed. If I guess right, `random.bat` sets the variable `num`. So

```
if %num% GEQ %eDEX% (
```

expands to (assuming `%dDEX%` is `10`):

```
if GEQ 10
```

which will give you that error.

```
if !num! GEQ %eDEX% (
```

should solve it.